# Packaging Sencha Touch 2.2.1 with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2

We are trying to package a hello world application made in sencha touch 2.2.1 with phonegap.

We can't get passed the phonegap spash screen.

Anyone can provide some good tutorial on how to package sencha toush 2.2.1 with Phonegap?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of phonegap you will be using?

Comment: We are finally using Cordova 2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were finally able to make it work. Our problem is that we  imported app.json from a fresh created apps and edited it. We were blocked on some unnecessary libraries used which gave us warnign like ext.msg, ext.select which were of no use to us. We are ok now after removing them